# Property does not exist using yargs and typescript

Tags: typescript, yargs

I am trying to parse a command line with yargs in typescript and it doesn't work:

```
import yargs from 'yargs';

const argv = yargs
    .option('label', {
    alias: 'l',
    describe: 'Execute bot with these labels',
    demandOption: false,
    type: 'string',
    })
    .option('console', {
    alias: 'c',
    describe: 'Log to console',
    demandOption: false,
    type: 'boolean',
    })
    .help()
    .alias('help', 'h')
    .argv;

if(argv.label){
    console.log('label')
}
```

The compiler throws and error:

```
Property 'label' does not exist on type '{ [x: string]: unknown; label: string | undefined; console: boolean | undefined; _: (string | number)[]; $0: string; } | Promise<{ [x: string]: unknown; label: string | undefined; console: boolean | undefined; _: (string | number)[]; $0: string; }>'.
  Property 'label' does not exist on type 'Promise<{ [x: string]: unknown; label: string | undefined; console: boolean | undefined; _: (string | number)[]; $0: string; }>'
```

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, `argv` may return a promise which is complicating the returned type.

Instead of calling `argv`, try calling `.parseSync()` instead. Then TypeScript knows what it is working with and `label` will be an expected property.